# 'Spiky Periodic Things' - Do these objects have a name, and is there a method for finding the boundary curves?

Tags: sequences-and-series, curves, periodic-functions

This question was originally about evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nix}$, but I figured out the answer about half way through writing it. So instead, I decided to ask a slightly different question.

Now, obviously, the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nix}$ does not converge - however, the closure of the set of points $(x,z)$ given by $z=\sum_{n=0}^\omega e^{nix}$ is bounded for arbitrarily large $\omega$; the object formed by these points is well defined as $\omega\to\infty$.

This becomes clear when you break the sum into a real and imaginary part:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nix}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos{nx}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin{nx}$$

Both sums form bounded sets, and the boundary is clearly another periodic function with vertical asymptotes at integer multiples of $2\pi$.

[image]
[image]

The resulting object can be expressed (admittedly awkwardly) as a piece-wise set-valued function of a single real variable $x$:

$$r_1(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\csc{\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\qquad r_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\csc{\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}$$

$$m_1(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\tan{\frac{x}{4}}\qquad m_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cot{\frac{x}{4}}$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}[r_1(x),r_2(x)]+i[m_1(x),m_2(x)]&\cot{\frac{x}{4}}>0\\ \mathbb{C}&\cot{\frac{x}{4}}=0^{\pm1}\\ [r_2(x),r_1(x)]+i[m_2(x),m_1(x)]&\cot{\frac{x}{4}}<0\end{cases}$$

Using $0^{-1}=\pm\infty$, $\quad Y_1+Y_2=\left\{y_1+y_2\mid y_1\in Y_1\land y_2\in Y_2\right\}$, and $iY=\left\{iy\mid y\in Y\right\}$. (If there is a more elegant way to write this, *please* tell me).

Naturally my next question was whether or not other 'spiky summations' exist, so I played around with different periodic functions, trying to get the summation to 'converge' to a bounded shape. After experimenting for a while, it seems that there is an entire class of these objects - which have interesting geometric and statistical properties.

[image]

Do these objects have a name? And is there a general method for finding the bounding curves given the summation used to generate them?

Comment: The more elegant way to write $\left\{y_1\in\mathbb{R}\mid r_1(x)\leq y_1\leq r_2(x)\right\}$ is $[r_1(x),r_2(x)]$.

Comment: Also, instead of bounding the limit set of the series by a rectangle in the complex plane, it would be even more elegant to say that it's a subset of a certain circle. You can find the center and radius of this circle using the geometric series formula.

Comment: @ChrisCulter How do I use the geometric series formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is very easy to explain when you view the sum as a geometric series.  We have a closed formula $$\sum_{n=0}^\omega e^{nix}=\frac{e^{(\omega+1)ix}-1}{e^{ix}-1}$$ and the bounding curves you are finding are just what you get by maximizing and minimizing the real and imaginary parts of $$\frac{w-1}{e^{ix}-1}$$ where $w$ is allowed to range over the unit circle.  When $\omega$ is large, $e^{(\omega+1)ix}$ is cycling through the entire unit circle very quickly as $x$ changes (while the denominator $e^{ix}-1$ is changing slowly), and so the real and imaginary parts of the sum quickly oscillate between the maximum and minimum values where $w$ ranges over the unit circle.

Explicitly, to find the real and imaginary parts we write $w=a+bi$ and find $$\frac{w-1}{e^{ix}-1}=\frac{a-1+bi}{\cos x-1+i\sin x}=\frac{a(\cos x-1)+b\sin x+1-\cos x}{(\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x}+i\frac{-a\sin x+b(\cos x-1)+\sin x}{(\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x}.$$  By Cauchy-Schwarz, given the constraint $a^2+b^2=1$, we maximize or minimize $a(\cos x-1)+b\sin x$ by making $(a,b)$ a scalar multiple of $(\cos x-1,\sin x)$, so that $a=\pm\frac{\cos x-1}{\sqrt{(\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x}}$ and $b=\pm\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{(\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x}}$.  This tells us that when $2-2\cos x$ is positive, the real part is bounded by $$\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{(\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x}{((\cos x-1)^2+\sin^2 x)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\csc(x/2).$$
Similarly, the imaginary part is bounded by $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\pm\frac{1}{2}\csc(x/2)$$ which is $\frac{1}{2}\cot(x/4)$ or $-\frac{1}{2}\tan(x/4)$ depending on the sign chosen.

The tangent-like appearance of the imaginary part graph (with half the period of the bounding curves) is explained by the fact that the *average* value between the oscillations is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1}{2}\cot(x/2)$.  In other words, the imaginary part is the graph of $\frac{1}{2}\cot(x/2)$ superimposed with oscillations whose peaks behave like $\frac{1}{2}\csc(x/2)$.

The bounding curves for other similar summations can be found in the same way, by writing everything in terms of complex exponentials and then summing as a geometric series.  In particular, the same method should work for three of the four examples you presented at the end (the exception being $\sum (-1)^n \cos^2(n/(x-n))$, which is really not the same sort of sum at all and has very different behavior).

Comment: Ah, now I see what ChrisCulter meant about the geometric series. You might want to double-check your answer, by the way.

Comment: Oops, I missed some square roots when optimizing.  Your bounding curves were correct. :)

Comment: Also, in this case it works out to be the same, but shouldn't the geometric series give $\frac{1-e^{(\omega+1)ix}}{1-e^{ix}}$ (with everything after that having the same sign change)?

Comment: That's the same: you just multiply the numerator and denominator by $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The doubly infinite sum is known as Dirac comb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb.